# Flex 3 to Flash 4 - Line charts are not displaying correctly

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flex3, linechart

I have migrated Flex 3 application to Flash 4 AIR application. The same code below is showing charts differently in two different scenarios. The first image is the correct one where as the second one is not showing correctly. It seems vertical axes are not updating dynamically. Please let me know if any change is required so that both shows the graphs.

```
    <mx:LineChart id="lcPatientChart" showDataTips="true" horizontalCenter="0" width="950">

    <mx:seriesFilters>
        <mx:Array/>
    </mx:seriesFilters>

    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:DateTimeAxis dataUnits="months" labelUnits="months" alignLabelsToUnits="false" labelFunction="formatDate"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>

    <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left" axis="{v1}"/>
        <mx:AxisRenderer placement="right" axis="{v2}"/>
        <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{v3}" minorTickPlacement="none" tickPlacement="none" labelGap="0"
            showLabels="false" showLine="false" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
        <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{v4}" minorTickPlacement="none" tickPlacement="none" labelGap="0"
            showLabels="false" showLine="false" visible="false" includeInLayout="false"/>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:series>

        <mx:LineSeries id="lsCB4Abs" xField="assayDate" yField="cd4Abs"
            dataProvider="{_cd4ChartData}" displayName="CD4"
            fill="{scBlue}" stroke="{sBlue}" lineStroke="{lsBlue}" visible="true" >
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis id="v1" title="CD4 Count (Cells/mm3)"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:DiamondItemRenderer />
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:LineSeries>

        <mx:LineSeries id="lsViralLoad" xField="assayDate" yField="viralLoad"
            dataProvider="{_vlChartData}" displayName="Viral Load"
            fill="{scGreen}" stroke="{sGreen}" lineStroke="{lsGreen}" visible="true">
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis id="v2" title="Viral Load (Copies/ml)"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:DiamondItemRenderer/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:LineSeries>

        <mx:AreaSeries id="asTherapy" xField="therapyDate" yField="therapy" form="horizontal" displayName="Therapy"
            areaStroke="{sGreenTransparent}" areaFill="{scGreenTransparent}" dataProvider="{_therapyChartData}" visible="true">
            <mx:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis id="v3"/>
            </mx:verticalAxis>
        </mx:AreaSeries>

        <component:CustomPlotSeries id="psSpecimen" dataProvider="{_specimenChartData}"   
            xField="specimenDate" yField="specimen" 
            displayName="Specimen" 
            fill="{scRedTransparent}" stroke="{sRedTransparent}" visible="true">
            <component:verticalAxis>
                <mx:LinearAxis id="v4" maximum="1.05" minimum="0"/>
            </component:verticalAxis>
            <component:itemRenderer >
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:CircleItemRenderer />
                </mx:Component>
            </component:itemRenderer>
        </component:CustomPlotSeries>

    </mx:series>

</mx:LineChart>
```

[image]
[image]